# Reading variable outside of function

Tags: jquery, var

I'm trying to use a `var` set within another function. How could I accomplish this?

```
$.getJSON(accountProjects, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        if (v.name == firebase_uid) {
            var project_hash_id = v.name;
            $('span').text(v.hashedId);
            return;
        }
    })
});

$('div').text(project_hash_id);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` has a callback .

Put your code inside `$.getJSON` success

```
$.getJSON(accountProjects, function (data) {
    var project_hash_id ="";
    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        if (v.name == firebase_uid) {
            project_hash_id = v.name;
            $('span').text(v.hashedId);
            return;
        }
    })
    $('div').text(project_hash_id);
});
```